# spring boot calling method automatically at different times set by different users

Tags: java, spring, automation, timer, schedule

I am trying to find a way to run a method at a specific time set by different users, let me explain!

Let's suppose we have 2 sites: siteA and siteB and those sites have admins: adminA and adminB respectively.

Each admin can create a work schedule in which the rabbitmq queues in his site are launched.
Right now, each admin launch his queues manually.

What i want is, lets say for exemple:
   adminA created a work schedule from 08:00 to 18:00
   adminB created a work schedule from 09:00 to 17:30

I want the method that launches a site queues to be executed at the time specified by the admin of that site so : 
queueA1, queueA2, queueA3... launched at 08:00
queueB1, queueB2... launched at 09:30

lets suppose the method called launchQueues(String siteId)

I have learned about @Scheduled but it seems like it is only applicable when i want to call a method in a fixed time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a common job which is scheduled to run every n minutes. This job can find any queue that need to be launched at that time interval and then launch it.

e.g. This job is scheduled for every 5 mins.

At 9:00 am, findQueuesToLaunch() method will find the queues that need to be launched at 9:00 am and not already running.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/5 * * * ?")
public void launchQueue() {

    List<String> queues = findQueuesToLaunch();
    
    for (String queueId in queues) {
      launchQueue(queueId);  
    }

}
```

Comment: i thought about implementing it this way but i thought there may be some performance issues if it is run each 5 min ? or it is fine ?

Comment: Either way, this is probably the easiest approach and maybe the best one